# Facebook SDK v4.0 for android doesn't show app invites on client side

Tags: android, facebook-apps, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-app-requests

I am trying to send app invites through the Facebook SDK v4.0 on Android. I am unable to figure out once I send the invite through my app, no notification is generated on the user's profile nor can the user see any invite of the sort.

I send the invite through:

```
 if (AppInviteDialog.canShow()) {
        AppInviteContent content = new AppInviteContent.Builder()
                .setApplinkUrl(appLinkUrl)
                //.setPreviewImageUrl(previewImageUrl)
                .build();
        AppInviteDialog.show(this, content);
    }
```

Comment: Do you sending invites to test users? Cause by default, your app can only send invites to testers. You can set them in the your developer menu - "Roles" - https://developers.facebook.com/apps/{Your app id}/roles/

Comment: Yes I have tried sending them to testers but they still aren't showing up.

Comment: Does your `appLinkUrl` point to a site that has the right kind of metadata? See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/android#app_links